# Allow 'mail' to read postfix-virtual created accounts?

Tags: linux, postfix

With my setup all my mail goes into `/home/vmail/(site.com)/(username)/new/`

Of course this is great, but the "mail" command only reads it if its in /home/vmail/new, how do I read mail with the 'mail' command if it's all in virtual directories?

If this is not possible, how could I read that mail?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying what your "mail" command is... So I will have to guess.
For example, on most of my systems, "mail" is a simple SMTP relay, not a mail reader...

My guess: the "mail" command you refer to is based on unix accounts, you seem to be using a virtual mail system with one unix account and many virtual mail accounts so this will not be possible without some work. Other clients like courier-imapd/courier-popd support this out of the box, but I very much doubt that any command line email reader will.

One hack that might work would be to create symlinks to all the "/new/" (and "/cur/" if you want read mail too) directories from "/home/vmail/new/" named after each account it is for. You could also automate this:

- /home/vmail/site_com_username -> /home/vmail/site.com/username/new/
- /home/vmail/site2_com_user2 -> /home/vmail/site2.com/user2/new

That is your assuming your current "mail" command looks for mail in "/home/vmail" (dubious - often they look for a ".maildir" mailbox) and that it understands mail subdirectories. If not, then get one that does support this.

Comment: Have you looked into the `mail` command on your systems? You might be surprised!

Comment: Some of them have mailx (a popular choice on most Linux distros), some of them have it symlinked to sendmail (or postfix), some of them have nothing at all, etc.. How is this "surprising"? AFAIK, on *nix systems the norm is to have "mail" provide a sendmail like interface (for things like cron etc). mailx if it is installed may provide more than this, but it is still based on unix user accounts, so the comment above stands. Or am I missing something? We are talking about mail retrieval, not delivery, right?